# Cambiar la estructura de un SP que utiliza cursores y pasarlo a una forma mas optima

Tags: sql, sql-server

Buen dia Amigos

Quisiera que me ayudaran a cambiar la estructura de un sp de pasarlo de cursor a otro metodo ya que demora demasiado tiempo. Quisiera que me ayudara a como poder cambiar de cursor a tablas temporales o algun otro metodo existente para reemplazar cursores.

Les dejo el sp original

```
create procedure usp_reas_redondeo (@id_proceso int)
as
 
/*********************************/
-- Redondeo de layers
 
-- Cursor para redondear a dos decimales las primas,
-- y en caso que de diferencia por redondeo, corrige uno de los valores
 
declare @id_pv              int
declare @cod_item           int
declare @id_linea           int
declare @imp_cesion_prima   numeric(18, 6)
declare @imp_cesion_riesgo  numeric(18, 6)
declare @nro_layer          int
 
declare @imp_max_dif            numeric(18, 6)
declare @imp_diferencia_suma    numeric(18, 6)
declare @imp_diferencia_prima   numeric(18, 6)
 
select @imp_max_dif = imp_param from tparametro where id_parametro = 179
 
/* TempTable(#tmp_cesion): Sumarizar iniformaci¢n desde tabla "wp_reasauto". */
create table #tmp_cesion
(id_proceso              int,
 id_pv                   int,
  cod_item                int,
    id_linea                int,
    imp_cesion_prima        numeric(18, 6),
    imp_cesion_riesgo       numeric(18, 6)
   )
 
/* TempTable(#tmp_diferencias): Sumarizar informaci¢n desde tabla "wi_mreas_layers". */
create table #tmp_diferencias
   (id_proceso              int,
    id_pv                   int,
    cod_item                int,
    id_linea                int,
    imp_suma_total          numeric(18, 6),
    imp_prima_total         numeric(18, 6)
   )
 
/* Cargar TempTable(#tmp_cesion). */
insert into #tmp_cesion(id_proceso, id_pv, cod_item, id_linea, imp_cesion_prima, imp_cesion_riesgo)
    select mi.id_proceso, mi.id_pv, mi.cod_item, mi.id_linea,
           sum(( mi.prima_riesgo) * -1 * mi.sn_acum_prima),    -- imp_cesion_prima
           sum(( mi.suma_riesgo)  * -1 * mi.sn_acum_suma )     -- imp_cesion_riesgo
    from wp_reasauto mi
    where mi.id_proceso = @id_proceso
    group by mi.id_proceso, mi.id_pv, mi.cod_item, mi.id_linea
 
/* Cargar TempTable(#tmp_diferencias). */
insert into #tmp_diferencias(id_proceso, id_pv, cod_item, id_linea, imp_suma_total, imp_prima_total)
select id_proceso, id_pv, cod_item, id_linea,
       isnull(sum(a_distribuir), 0) as imp_suma_total,
       isnull(sum(imp_prima), 0) as imp_prima_total
from wi_mreas
where id_proceso = @id_proceso
group by id_proceso, id_pv, cod_item, id_linea
 
declare cur_redondeo cursor for
    select tc.id_proceso, tc.id_pv, tc.cod_item, tc.id_linea, tc.imp_cesion_prima, tc.imp_cesion_riesgo,
           (tc.imp_cesion_riesgo - td.imp_suma_total) as imp_diferencia_suma,
           (tc.imp_cesion_prima  - td.imp_prima_total) as imp_diferencia_prima
    from #tmp_cesion tc, #tmp_diferencias td
    where tc.id_proceso = td.id_proceso and tc.id_pv = td.id_pv and
          tc.cod_item = td.cod_item and tc.id_linea = td.id_linea and
          tc.id_proceso = @id_proceso
 
open cur_redondeo
fetch cur_redondeo into @id_proceso, @id_pv, @cod_item, @id_linea, @imp_cesion_prima, @imp_cesion_riesgo,
                        @imp_diferencia_suma, @imp_diferencia_prima
while (@@sqlstatus = 0)
begin
    -- SUMA
    if (@imp_diferencia_suma <> 0 and abs(@imp_diferencia_suma) < @imp_max_dif)
    begin
        -- Elije el registro a actualizar: (Toma el de mayor prima cedida)
        select @nro_layer = nro_layer
        from wi_mreas
        where id_proceso = @id_proceso and id_pv = @id_pv and
              cod_item = @cod_item and id_linea = @id_linea
        order by a_distribuir desc
 
        -- Lo actualiza:
        update wi_mreas
            set a_distribuir = a_distribuir + @imp_diferencia_suma
        where id_proceso = @id_proceso and id_pv = @id_pv and
              cod_item = @cod_item and id_linea = @id_linea and nro_layer = @nro_layer
    end
 
    -- PRIMA
    if (@imp_diferencia_prima <> 0 and abs(@imp_diferencia_prima) < @imp_max_dif)
    begin
        -- Elije el registro a actualizar: (Toma el de mayor prima cedida)
        select @nro_layer = nro_layer
        from wi_mreas
        where id_proceso = @id_proceso and id_pv = @id_pv and
              cod_item = @cod_item and id_linea = @id_linea
        order by imp_prima desc
 
        -- Lo actualiza:
        update wi_mreas
            set imp_prima = imp_prima + @imp_diferencia_prima
        where id_proceso = @id_proceso and id_pv = @id_pv and
              cod_item = @cod_item and id_linea = @id_linea and nro_layer = @nro_layer
    end
 
    fetch cur_redondeo into @id_proceso, @id_pv, @cod_item, @id_linea, @imp_cesion_prima, @imp_cesion_riesgo,
                            @imp_diferencia_suma, @imp_diferencia_prima
 
end
close cur_redondeo
deallocate cursor cur_redondeo
 
 
RETURN (0)
```

Agradezco su valioso apoyo.
Me colaboran por favor con este inconveniente que tengo esto ya que se me ha encomendado la tarea de mejorar los procesos de la base de datos y he detectado un uso exagerado de cursores dentro de la base de datos.

quiero que ustedes me apoyen a aprender como cambiar estos curosres.

Agradeciendo de antemano todo su apoyo brindado

Answer (score 2):

Una de las posibles soluciones es la aplicación de ctes correlativos.

Como verás en el código, que es posible que contenga algún tipo de error de sintaxis, pues no tengo la definición de las tablas, realmente el uso de las tablas temporales, para luego realizar un cursor, se puede sustituir por lecturas en tablas de expresión común, y entre ellas se relacionan (conjunto origen) para en la salida de las ctes correlativas, realizar una update.

La update, puede utilizar una expresión case para modificar o no la columna, que es la que utilizaban en el if

Por facilidad en la explicación te he puesto un conjunto nroLayer, aunque se podía haber utilizado por ejemplo un row_number dentro de los ctes y escoger solo la ultima fila, sin tener que leer de nuevo la tabla wi_mareas.

También he aplicado un cambio de sintaxis de Sql-86 a Sql-92

Estos ctes correlativos también se podían utilizar con las tablas temporales, si de momento su construcción es un handicap. Pero si el volumen de datos no es exagerado, tienen un rendimiento brutalmente bueno en comparación con las tablas temporales.

```
alter procedure usp_reas_redondeo 
(   
    @id_proceso int
)
as
 
select @imp_max_dif = imp_param from tparametro where id_parametro = 179;

With tmp_cesion 
As (
    /* TempTable(#tmp_cesion): Sumarizar iniformaci¢n desde tabla "wp_reasauto". */
    select mi.id_proceso
         , mi.id_pv
         , mi.cod_item
         , mi.id_linea
         , sum(( mi.prima_riesgo) * -1 * mi.sn_acum_prima) as imp_cesion_prima
         , sum(( mi.suma_riesgo)  * -1 * mi.sn_acum_suma ) as imp_cesion_riesgo
    from wp_reasauto mi
    where mi.id_proceso = @id_proceso
    group by mi.id_proceso, mi.id_pv, mi.cod_item, mi.id_linea
), tmp_diferencias AS (
/* TempTable(#tmp_diferencias): Sumarizar informaci¢n desde tabla "wi_mreas_layers". */
    select id_proceso
         , id_pv
         , cod_item
         , id_linea
         , isnull(sum(a_distribuir), 0) as imp_suma_total
         , isnull(sum(imp_prima), 0) as imp_prima_total
    from wi_mreas
    where id_proceso = @id_proceso
    group by id_proceso, id_pv, cod_item, id_linea
),origen as (
 select tc.id_proceso
      , tc.id_pv
      , tc.cod_item
      , tc.id_linea
      , tc.imp_cesion_prima
      , tc.imp_cesion_riesgo,
        (tc.imp_cesion_riesgo - td.imp_suma_total) as imp_diferencia_suma,
        (tc.imp_cesion_prima  - td.imp_prima_total) as imp_diferencia_prima
 from tmp_cesion tc inner join tmp_diferencias td 
        on      tc.id_proceso = td.id_proceso 
            and tc.id_pv = td.id_pv 
            and tc.cod_item = td.cod_item 
            and tc.id_linea = td.id_linea 
       where
       tc.id_proceso = @id_proceso
), nroLayer as (
Select top(1) m.nroLayer 
from wi_mreas m inner join tmp_cesion tc 
   on     tc.id_proceso=m.id_Proceso
      and tc.id_pv = m.id_pv
      and tc.cod_item = m.cod_item
      and tc.id_linea = m.id_linea
order by a_distribuir desc
)
update m set m.a_distribuir = case when o.imp_diferencia_suma <> 0 and abs(o.imp_diferencia_suma < @imp_max_dif)  
                                    then a_distribuir + o.imp_diferencia_suma 
                                    else a_distribuir end
           , m.imp_prima = case when o.imp_diferencia_suma <> 0 and abs(o.imp_diferencia_suma < @imp_max_dif)  
                    then imp_prima + imp_diferencia_prima
                    else imp_prima end;

RETURN (0) --*****
```

[Cte correlativo](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2018/12/18/with-cte-tablas-de-expresion-comun-2-correlativos/)

[Row Number](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2019/11/11/row-number-numerar-filas/)